# What activation function should I use in my neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network comprised of a Concatenation layer (that combines 2 inputs), one Dense layer and one output layer (Dense).

This neural network is expected to receive a numerical value (position of drone ranging from 0 to 100) and an array of numbers ranging from 0 to 3. (e.g: `array = [0, 2, 1, 3, ...]`)

These inputs are concatenated then fed to a Dense layer then the network has to choose a new position for the drone out of the 100 possible positions, therefore, the output layer has 100 possibilities to choose from.

The code is as follows:

```
def create_pos_dnn(self):  
        # Initialize the inputs
        uav_current_position = Input(shape=(1,), name='pos')
        ues_requests = Input(shape=(7,), name='requests')
        
        # Put them in a list
        list_inputs = [uav_current_position, ues_requests]
        
        # Merge all input features into a single large vector
        x = layers.concatenate(list_inputs)
        
        # Add a Hidden (Dense) Layer
        dense_layer = Dense((requests_input_shape[0] + pos_input_shape[0]) // 2, activation="sigmoid")(x)
        
        # Output layer
        output_layer = Dense(output_nodes, activation="sigmoid")(dense_layer)

        model = Model(inputs=list_inputs, outputs=output_layer)
        
        opt = Adam(lr=self.learning_rate, decay=self.epsilon_decay)
        
        model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)
        
        # return the DNN
        return model
```

The architecture is as follows:
[image: NN Architecture]

I have some concerns:
What activation functions should I use for the hidden layer and the output layer and why ?
What loss function should I use ?
And how many neurons should the hidden dense layer have ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more: what is the output range? can the output have negative values? is there a maximum value? are the outputs depending on each other?

Comment: I'm new to this so bare with me a little. So I have 100 possible outputs, and I'm gonna choose one of them, which means that one neuron would have the value 1 and the others a value 0 and I'm gonna pick the one with the value 1. Am I correct ?

Comment: Does that mean I should pick a linear activation function ?

Comment: It is still not clear to me but based on what I understood: if you have 100 choices and there is only 1 correct position from the 100, then what you need is softmax activation as this is a classification problem. At the end, it will provide you a probability of each position that the sum will yield to 1.

Comment: Ah yes, makes perfect sense! And it doesn't matter what activation function to use in the hidden layer ? It's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, the activation in the hidden layers doesn't make different to the target but it makes difference for the training overall.. Try to start with the most common activation which is relu or elu.